# register_chrdev_region fails for major number 512

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to understand register_chrdev_region. I know major number is 12 bits and minor number is 20 bits out of 32 bits device number.

Wrote a sample code, which can test register_chrdev_region through module parameters

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

int major_number = 120;
int minor_number = 0;
char *device_name = "mychardev";
int count = 1;
dev_t devicenumber;

module_param(major_number, int, 0);
module_param(minor_number, int, 0);
module_param(count, int, 0);
module_param(device_name, charp, 0);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
static int test_hello_init(void)
{

    devicenumber = MKDEV(major_number, minor_number);
    printk("Major Number :%d\n", MAJOR(devicenumber));
    printk("Minor Number :%d\n", MINOR(devicenumber));
    printk("Count:%d\n", count);
    printk("Device Name:%s\n", device_name);

    if (!register_chrdev_region(devicenumber, count, device_name))
        printk("Device number registered\n");
    else
        printk("Device number registration Failed\n");

    return 0;
}

static void test_hello_exit(void)
{
    unregister_chrdev_region(devicenumber, count);
}

module_init(test_hello_init);
module_exit(test_hello_exit);
```

When i loaded the module with:

```
sudo insmod ./hello.ko major_number=512 device_name=abc
```

register_chrdev_region failed with the following message:

```
CHRDEV "abc" major requested (512) is greater than the maximum (511)
```

What does this means. Do we have only 10 bits for major number?

Comment: The maximum of 511 is `CHRDEV_MAJOR_MAX - 1`, where `CHRDEV_MAJOR_MAX` is defined as 512 in `<linux/fs.h>`.

Comment: So do you mean major number is 10 bits

Comment: There is room for 12 bits of major number, but only 9 bits are currently used.